# Docker-compose.yml Is not working for elasticserch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, elastic-stack

**Version Used:**

```
Docker-compose = 1.3.2
Docker = 1.12.3
Os: Ubuntu-14.04LTS
```

## 1: Compose file contents:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
elk: 
  image: elasticsearch:latest       
  ports:  
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  volumes:
    - ./Elasticsearch/data:/etc/elasticsearch/data
    - ./Elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/etc/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  command: bash -c "service elasticsearch start"
  tty : true
```

## 2: $ Running compose file:

```
docker-compose up
```

**Getting Following:**

```
Attaching to elkdockerdir_elk_1
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:18,458][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:18,573][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [UERHECj] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda6)]], net usable_space [409.6gb], net total_space [442.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:18,573][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [UERHECj] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:18,576][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] node name [UERHECj] derived from node ID; set [node.name] to override
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:18,579][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] version[5.0.0], pid[1], build[253032b/2016-10-26T05:11:34.737Z], OS[Linux/3.13.0-32-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_111/25.111-b14]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [ingest-common]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [lang-expression]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [lang-groovy]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [lang-painless]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,066][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [percolator]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,067][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [reindex]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,067][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [transport-netty3]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,067][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,067][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [UERHECj] no plugins loaded
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:19,149][WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,424][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] initialized
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,424][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] starting ...
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,571][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [UERHECj] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,576][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [UERHECj] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
elk_1 | ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
elk_1 | max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,587][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] stopping ...
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,608][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] stopped
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,608][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] closing ...
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T06:28:20,620][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [UERHECj] closed
elkdockerdir_elk_1 exited with code 78
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

## 3: $ Check the container:

```
docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
    a8799b8fe969        elasticsearch:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   About a minute ago   Exited (78) About a minute ago                       elkdockerdir_elk_1
```

**Partial solution**:

`service elasticsearch` is not keep running, so the  after adding `bash -c "service elasticsearch start && tail -f /dev/null` its working fine ,
Please check after `$ docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                              NAMES
bfbc12a69a8a        elasticsearch:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   13 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elkdockerdir_elk_1
```

running but when testing elasticsearch by using curl:
`$  curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'`
its giving error like: 
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Also `http://localhost:9200` is not working...

Not getting the exact issue...

**Questions:**

1: How to run docker-compose.yml with commands i.e. `command: bash -c "service elasticsearch start"` for given docker-compose and docker version ?

Comment: The official elasticsearch image is starting elasticsearch in the foreground, not as a service (https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/03a5bda1ff2d27b000e5236082b26975a6a44c2e/1.4/Dockerfile#L20): `CMD ["elasticsearch"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks it is trivial error in the `docker-compose.yml` in the `command` statement.

**Change from:**

```
command: bash -c "service elasticsearch start"
```

**To:**

```
command: service elasticsearch start
```

or

```
command: [service, elasticsearch, start]
```

**UPDATE:** based on the comments.

Looks like `command` statement isn't needed in this case.
Removed `command` statement altogether from `docker-compose.yml` and re run `docker-compose up` command.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
elk: 
  image: elasticsearch:latest       
  ports:  
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  tty : true

docker-compose up
Creating cmp1_elk_1
Attaching to cmp1_elk_1
elk_1  | -14T09:28:12,095][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elk_1  | -14T09:28:14,167][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [9KYASyV] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda2)]], net usable_space [44.1gb], net total_space [55.1gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:14,168][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [9KYASyV] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:14,174][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [9KYASyV] node name [9KYASyV] derived from node ID; set [node.name] to override
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:14,286][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [9KYASyV] version[5.0.0], pid[1], build[253032b/2016-10-26T05:11:34.737Z], OS[Linux/4.4.27-moby/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_111/25.111-b14]
elk_1  | -14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [ingest-common]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [lang-expression]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [lang-groovy]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,109][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [lang-painless]
elk_1  | -14T09:28:22,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [percolator]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [reindex]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [transport-netty3]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:22,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [9KYASyV] no plugins loaded
elk_1  | -14T09:28:22,966][WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead
elk_1  | -14T09:28:28,813][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [9KYASyV] initialized
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:28,813][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [9KYASyV] starting ...
elk_1  | -14T09:28:29,432][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [9KYASyV] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
elk_1  | -14T09:28:29,438][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [9KYASyV] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
elk_1  | -14T09:28:34,694][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [9KYASyV] [gc][young][3][4] duration [3.1s], collections [1]/[3.8s], total [3.1s]/[4.4s], memory [163.3mb]->[81.6mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [132.2mb]->[3.1mb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [16.6mb]->[10.9mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [14.5mb]->[67.5mb]/[1.8gb]}
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:34,696][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [9KYASyV] [gc][3] overhead, spent [3.1s] collecting in the last [3.8s]
elk_1  | -14T09:28:34,780][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [9KYASyV] new_master {9KYASyV}{9KYASyViTaOsIAx7vjSZZQ}{NvfMmitMSNCXVkpHo7GzmQ}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
elk_1  | -14T09:28:34,895][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [9KYASyV] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
elk_1  | [2016-11-14T09:28:34,895][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [9KYASyV] started
elk_1  | -14T09:28:35,085][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [9KYASyV] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Now it is up and able to query too.

Also, `curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'` results below and hence it is working:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "9KYASyV",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "UTZ18I0QRWmg0LFKUDE3ew",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.0",
    "build_hash" : "253032b",
    "build_date" : "2016-10-26T05:11:34.737Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Also from your log, it is noticed that `vm.max_map_count` is low.  You may check [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) for more details.

Comment: Hi @Rao, I removed the command section from yml file, its works but 'service elasticsearch' is not running in 'elasticsearch' docker image, so for testing [http://localhost:9200] is not working also tested using curl... but its not showing but I added command like `command: bash -c "service elasticsearch start && tail -f /dev/null` it works but again `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_status'` is not running....

Comment: @Dhairya, does it have `service` command in path? Otherwise include with path?

Comment: If you see office elasticsearch image documentation, it says 9200, 9300 tcp ports are exposted. I believe, that is a http port, so it results `$ curl -s http://localhost:9300/?pretty;
This is not a HTTP port`

Comment: Hi @Rao, added path i.e `/usr/bin/service` but still not working but when i run `command: bash -c `service elasticsearch start && tail -f /dev/null`  its keep running but I think, elasticsearch service is not tunning.... testes using curl...

Comment: Hi @Rao I removed but still getting same problem .......    `elk_1 | [2016-11-14T09:47:49,785][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [402R0VQ] starting ...
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T09:47:49,890][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [402R0VQ] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T09:47:49,894][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [402R0VQ] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
elk_1 | [2016-11-14T09:47:49,982][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [402R0VQ] closed
elkdockerdir_elk_1 exited with code 78
 `

Comment: Hi @Rao I logged in container of elasticsearch using `docker run -it elasticsearh /bin/bash` and checked elastic search service status, it showed service is not running, so after running the service manually the curl command giving proper output, But how to pass command by using docker-compose.yml /

Comment: looks like you opened a ticket in docker git hub. Can you update in the question with your log, there must be some `ERROR` which can't be read well from your comment. Also updated my compose file contents in the question. YOu can try that.

Comment: Hi @Rao  for help I got the solution, as per our conversation the error is regarding to heap size i.e `elk_1 | max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
`, so I set heap size and its works fine now to change heap size `$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144 `.. Thanks again for your Help.....

Comment: @Dhairya, glad to know that it was helpful. You may upvote if that was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the docs of elastic search image. I think you should delete your `command` in docker-compose file.
your compose file should be like this

```
elk: 
  image: elasticsearch:latest       
  ports:  
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  volumes:
    - ./Elasticsearch/data:/etc/elasticsearch/data
    - ./Elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/etc/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  tty : true
```

Comment: Hi @Bui Ngoc Luan . I removed the command section from yml file, its works but 'service elasticsearch' is not running in 'elasticsearch' docker image, so for testing [http://localhost:9200] is not working also tested using curl... but its not showing but I added command like `command: bash -c "service elasticsearch start && tail -f /dev/null` it works but again `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_status'` is not running....